# Como desenhar molduras no console, junto com palavras acentuadas?

Tags: c, c++, acentuação, locale

Eu utilizo a função `BoxDraw` abaixo para desenhar molduras, num programa com saída em modo texto (console).

Não consigo utilizar esta função se usar palavras com acento, pois quando incluo a biblioteca `<locale>` (para as palavras do menu como "Relatório", por exemplo) buga a saída da minha moldura da `BoxDraw`.

O que posso fazer para utilizar em conjunto molduras e os acentos corretamente?

O código para desenhar as molduras é esse:

```
void BoxDraw(int posX, int posY, int width, int height){
    char TL = 201, TR = 187, BL = 200, BR = 188, LINE = 205, COLUMN = 186;
    gotoxy(posX, posY);
    cout << TL;
    for (int i = 0; i < width - 1; i++){
        cout << LINE;
    }
    cout << TR << endl;
    //columns
    for (int i = 0; i < height - 1; i++){
        gotoxy(posX, posY + i + 1);
        cout << COLUMN << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < height - 1; i++){
        gotoxy(posX + width, posY + i + 1);
        cout << COLUMN << endl;
    }
    //endcolumns
    gotoxy(posX, posY + height);
    cout << BL;
    for (int i = 0; i < width - 1; i++){
        cout << LINE;
    }
    cout << BR << endl;
}

void sideMenu(Product *p[], int n, int op) {
    static int indice; indice = Product::getNumProduct();
    switch (op) {
    case 1:
        system("cls");      
        insertProduct(p, n, indice);
        getEnterFromInput();
        mainMenu(p, n);
        break;
    case 2:
        system("cls");
        search(p, indice);
        getEnterFromInput();
        mainMenu(p, n);
        break;
    case 3:
        system("cls");
        deleteProduct(p);
        getEnterFromInput();
        mainMenu(p, n);
        break;
    case 4:
        system("cls");
        //debitarValor(c, n);
        getEnterFromInput();
        mainMenu(p, n);
        break;
    case 5:
        system("cls");
        sale(p);
        getEnterFromInput();
        mainMenu(p, n);
        break;
    case 6:
        system("cls");
        report(p);
        getEnterFromInput();
        mainMenu(p, n);
        break;
    case 0:
        system("cls");
        cout << "Saindo!" << endl;
        exit(1);
        break;
    default:
        system("cls");
        cout << "Opção inválida!" << endl;
        getEnterFromInput();
        mainMenu(p, n);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isso depende muito do suporte do OS. Como seu código está chamando o `cls`, imagino que se trate de Windows. De qualquer forma, melhor [edit] a postagem e acrescentar estes detalhes. O problema é que os acentos ocupam o lugar dos caracteres de moldura quando você usa Codepages, por uma limitação da quantidade de caracteres possível. Para usar simultaneamente, vai precisar forçar o console em modo Unicode: `chcp 65001`. Além disso, vai ter que usar outros códigos no lugar do TL, TR etc, pois em unicode eles ficam do U+2500 em diante. http://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/box-drawing/

Comment: Aqui tem exemplo de como usar unicode, com isso e mais a tabela de caracteres de bloco acima, acho que você consegue: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34068/Unicode-Output-to-the-Windows-Console - Se conseguir resolver, pode postar como resposta no campo abaixo para ajudar outras pessoas. De qualquer forma, pode ser que alguém já poste algo antes. Ah, não se esqueça de que o editor de código também tem que ser configurado para salvar em UTF-8 neste caso, se for usar strings literais acentuadas.

Comment: Editei um pouco sua pergunta, acho que agora só falta você acrescentar o OS usado, e se puder, um [mcve] com o problema acontecendo.

Comment: Tente usar isso aqui: [https://github.com/nsf/termbox](https://github.com/nsf/termbox). Acho que utilizando-o você consegue um bom resultado.